# Azure Web App with Linux and bundling GLIBC 2.29 with my ASP.NET Core 7 App

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I have an ASP.NET Core 7 application hosted on Azure Web App Linux. I am using a native package that uses **GLIBC 2.29** from Linux.
When I run the SSH, I get: `ASP .NETCore Version: 7.0.0` and when I run `ldd --version`, I get:

```
ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.28-10+deb10u2) 2.28
```

The native package is looking for GLIBC 2.29 and if I use an older version of the native package that relies on GLIBC 2.28, then it works as expected.

My questions:

- Can I bundle the GLIB 2.29 files with my release? Does this even work with native stuff (I can hear C++ developers laughing about bundling files)?
- Can I have some setting on Azure Web App to request GLIB 2.29?

N.B. I am aware that I can use Docker for selecting specific components, but I am leaving this as the last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I bundle the GLIB 2.29 files with my release?

Yes, it is possible to bundle the GLIB files with the release. But it is not a better approach to do, as we may get the compatibility issues.

Deployed  `ASP.NET Core 7`  to  `Azure Linux App service`.
When I checked the version, Even I have the same 2.28 version.

[image]

In the deployed `Azure Linux App`, open the SSH.

Link to open SSH -  `https://YourWebAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/webssh/host`.

I have tried to  `install/ update`  the latest version by using the below command.

```cs
apt-get install libc6
```

[image]

- As GLIBC 2.29 is not available in Azure Linux, we can download the source and install from  [GNU C Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/)  -  [Sourceware.org](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Glibc%20Timeline).

Check the below steps to [install](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Glibc-Install-HOWTO/) `GLIBC 2.29`  Version in local Linux.

Run the below commands.

```cs
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libc/glibc-2.29.tar.gz
tar -xvzf glibc-2.29.tar.gz
```

Navigate to the `glibc-2.29` root directory.

```cs
cd glibc-2.29
make 
make install
```

[image]

- This cannot be installed directly in `Azure Linux App Service`.We can follow the same process in `Linux Virtual Machine`.

> I can use Docker for selecting specific components

Yes,we can create a custom image in `Azure Linux app service` and deploy to `Azure Container Registry`.

Reference taken from  [zoomadmin](https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/libc6).

Comment: So, you are confirming that you cannot change the Web App Service (Linux) GLIBC version and you are recommending a Linux VM or a container.

Comment: This is what I got when I tried to update in Azure linux app service.

Comment: When I tried to update with `apt-get install libc6` command, it is saying 2.28 is the latest version available in Azure Linux App.

Comment: So,It is advised to update by downloading the source.